# Google Play Developer Console Pre-Launch Report: "Low Contrast" Behind Dialog

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing a single-activity application, and am using fragments to implement the various UI components.  When the user clicks "Options", for example, an "Options" fragment is loaded and displayed over the main application screen.  The "Options" fragment is set to match_parent for width and height, and it has a 70% opacity "mask" that "grays out" the content behind it.  When the Google Play Store runs its Pre-Launch Report, it complains that the controls from the main app UI has "low contrast" when the "Options" fragment is showing.

In this example, the red box is highlighting a button that is behind the Options pop-up.

[image: Example]

Is there some way to tell Android that the stuff in the background, behind the top-level fragment, isn't clickable/focusable/etc, without actually traversing the entire view and disabling, and then later re-enabling, all the main UI controls?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? We are experiencing what I think is a similar problem with keyboard showing over some buttons and the pre-launch report stating there is a contrast problem based on colors in keyboard.

Comment: I did not.  I wound up changing the design so that the game board and the options dialogs are all fragments, and I swap out the game board fragment with the options fragment when needed, and then pop back to the game board when the options dialog is closd.